# How to do word wrapping

Tags: php, html

I have created a table in PHP but the cells size is not fixed it expends when the input is long. Here is the Code.

```
echo "<div style=\"overflow-y: scroll; white-space: nowrap; height: 190px;\">\n";
        echo "<table cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" align=\"center\" width=\"100%\" id=\"clients\">\n";
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"2b2d5d\">\n";
        echo "<th align=\"left\" style=\"color: FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; padding: 5\">&nbsp;</th>\n";
        echo "<th align=\"left\" style=\"color: FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; padding: 5\">Name</th>\n";
        echo "<th align=\"left\" style=\"color: FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; padding: 5\">Address</th>\n";
        echo "<th align=\"left\" style=\"color: FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; padding: 5\">Phone</th>\n";
        echo "<th align=\"left\" style=\"color: FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; padding: 5\">Fax</th>\n";
```

I want to fixed the cells width please need help.
Thanks

Comment: did that help Talha? let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set % widths on the th tags .

```
<th style="width:20%;">
```

or you could just set a fixed width on certain columns if you preffered that design.

I would also advice you to move the inline css into a class to save you repeating the same code, and place it in a seperate css stylesheet. Incase your unfamiliar (or anyone who is reading) attach a stylesheet by placing the below in the head of the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
```

example class:

```
.myTableColumn{color: FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial; padding: 5;width:20%;}
```

Call it from the column:

```
<th class="myTableColumn">
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Even using the `wordwrap()` function (http://php.net/wordwrap) will not help as HTML will collapse whitespace and will treat it the same (of course you could wrap it in <pre> tags but then I'd just be getting pedantic).

Comment: Just a bit of an extension to this is that if you use a % width, the text will expand on larger resolutions. 20% of 768 pixels is different than 20% of 1050 pixels. Using a pixel width would be more proper IF you need it to be an exact width permanently. Also, the code is missing the semicolon after 20% :)

Comment: you don't need a semi colon for a single style definition, but i'll put it for you :)

Comment: You could also try nl2br(wordwrap())

Answer (score 0):

```
<th width="50"></th>
```

should do. If it doesn't

```
<th style="max-width: 50px;"></th>
```